# Count max value (text+number) occurrences with filtering a specific part of text in excel

Tags: excel

I'm having an excel column range (including blank cells) something like:

`00EGB00-GE001
00EGB00-GE001
00EGB00-GE001
00EGB00-GE001
00EGB00-GE002
00EGB00-GE002
00EGB00-GE002
00EGB00-GE002
00EGD20-GD101`

What I need is to **Count total number of similar values** and I'm stuck with the logic for counting total unique "similar" values... example "GE" & "GD" separately.

**How to count total number of unique "GE" values in the list?**
I thought `=COUNTIF(B:B,"*GE*")` should work but it does not. It gives total count of "GE" but I need to find unique count. Example GE001 & GE002 should be considered as 2 values in total.

Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT AGAIN:** Given further clarification below, and assuming that the data always has the same number of digits, one way to do it is by putting this in Column B:

`=RIGHT(A1,5)`

Then, if you have Excel 2007 or up, Copy and Paste Values and use Remove Duplicates to leave you with the unique values. Then remove the items with GD, either manually or using a formula.

In this case, the output is:

```
GE001
GE002
```

In this case, you can easily see that it's 2. If you have lots of values, you can use `COUNTA`. Is that what you want?

**YET ANOTHER EDIT BASED ON LAST COMMENT**: this is probably getting closer:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(A1:A9,9,2)="GE"),1/COUNTIF(A1:A9,A1:A9))`

Where the "GE" is hard-coded in the formula above you could also substitute a cell reference where you can alter the value.

Or, if you don't know where the text you want will be exactly because the number of characters change, this will work (but you'd need to be careful with what you were searching on because it might repeat somewhere else in the string):

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISERR(SEARCH("GE",A1:A9))<>TRUE),1/COUNTIF(A1:A9,A1:A9))`

Again, you can replace the "GE" with a cell reference.

As discovered below, though -- blank cells will cause this to fail. There IS almost definitely a way to cater for them (maybe using a `FREQUENCY` based Array Formula), but if you can live with cleaning out the blank cells then that would be one way of doing it.

**LAST EDIT: this will account for blank cells.** It is an Array Formula, and CAN be used on whole columns, but that will be quite slow as it takes up a fair bit of calculation effort:

`{=SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(A1:A9,9,2)="GE"),IF(ISBLANK(A1:A9),1,1/COUNTIF(A1:A9,A1:A9)))}`

As it's an Array Formula, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to input it.

Comment: I just want to find the total occurrences of "GE" in the range. Example in the above rage GE occurs 8 times, but in fact GE001 is one item and GE002 is another item so total (unique) value should be shown as 2 only.

Comment: Thx my friend u have really narrowed down the problem. Just a small part is missed in problem solving, in the range I showed as an example: the "GE: is followed by some numbers (001, 002). These numbers should also be taken into account while figuring the total quantity of GE. I will try again, I have to gather all text with "GE" in it, and then count unique occurrence in those ranges. Now checking the above range... we have total 8 occurrence of values having GE in it, but only unique Text/values are there (00EGB00-GE001 and 00EGB00-GE002)......  Did this makes sense now?

Comment: In my frenzy of edits, I think I might have got to the one that you need with the last edit. It ends up showing GE001 and GE002 as two separate uniques. And actually, if the text to the left of GE* and GD* doesn't change, you could do by copying the column, getting rid of the GD*s and then doing Remove Duplicates. Does that work? Or do you need it in a formula?

Comment: yupp that what I was doing till now, making separate columns and fetching "GE" values separately and countif them all

Comment: I was trying to do all that in a single formula so that I can change values (GE or GD) and fetch total values as-and-when required. Another reason is that I don't know what other values (except GE and GD) can come-up in the range, so I wanted to keep it as friendly as possible, otherwise its not intelligent thing to keep making new columns and filtering any new values introduced in the search ranges. What do u say?

Comment: have a look and see if the formula above does what you want

Comment: Is that working for u? *=SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(Grouping!B:B,9,2)="GE"),1/COUNTIF(Grouping!B:B,Grouping!B:B))* here it shows #div/0 error BTW i am using 2010

Comment: It's #DIV/0 for me with the whole column (i.e. B:B) but when I use the range it works. It's the blank cells -- that's causing a #DIV/0 error. You might need to dataclean the blank cells out.

Comment: Sadly the list is not in my hands and I can get it as the input in any way, removing non-blanks is not possible for me as the file shall not be altered in any way. That is why I've used "fetch values" as reference into another sheet named as "Grouping" in my working xls copy.

Comment: Check my last edit: I have accounted for blank cells.